# OSX Server can't be blessed anymore

Tags: macos, startup

I have a headless Mac Pro running as a server, with Mac OS 10.12 I can reach it via Terminal. I can no longer set the Startup Disk by running:

```
"bless -mount "/Volumes/Startupdisk" -setBoot.
```

Even `bless -info` gives me the following error:

> Assertion failed: (skylight_handle != NULL), function __get_skylight_handle_block_invoke, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Quartz2D/Quartz2D-1070.22.1/CoreGraphics/Services/Connection/SLShim.c, line 26.
>   Abort trap: 6

Comment: That sounds like it's trying to do something in the GUI (warning, confirmation dialog, requesting authorization, something like that) and it's failing because there's no display. Is it possible to temporarily attach a display (or set up a virtual one) to let it run/see what it is?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sudo bless....`?

Comment: I had to assign an startvolume from the GUI. After that blessing via terminal worked.